# Which URL to enter to access Geoserver via a browser?

Tags: geoserver, url

I installed Geoserver using ssh on a server which is hosting a website that I maintain. What will be the URL I need in order to access Geoserver via a browser?

I have tried using the the server host IP. https://nnn.nn.n.nnn/geoserver.

Edit. The server is LAMP and doesn't have Tomcat. I installed the Linux binary and have run the sh. start.sh from the bin directory.

Comment: did you change the port? otherwise you probably need to add :8080 to that url

Comment: the port on the ssh client is 22.

Comment: but you are not running GeoServer over SSH

Comment: with :8080 i get a connection timeout error

Comment: probably a firewall issue or jetty stopped when you logged out - did you use nohup?

Comment: Both my machine and the server are behind the same reverse proxy. Do I need to add the proxy details to the URL?

Comment: Die you try 8081? Works in my machine, 8080 was reserved

Answer (score 2):

As @iant said, you need to specify the port in the URL. If you didn't change anything, Jetty will be running at port 8080. 
In my opinion, I would advise to run Geoserver in Tomcat instead of Jetty which comes with the windows installer. You get the benefit of richer documentation and the ability to set a reverse proxy to run Tomcat behind a generic web server such as Apache which allows you to forego the need to specify the port in the URL.

Finally, please add the '*.../web*' thing at the end of the URL. Not sure if this should be the problem since this is normally added automatically by the Geoserver's routing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my installation is running. But you can define the structure.
http://yourIPAddress:8080/geoserver/web/